# How to convert a 32 bit floating point value to model it as a 8 bit unsingned fractional value with range 0-1.0

Tags: floating-point

I have some floating point reference C code. This code is eventually going to be ported/executed on a DSP processor(proprietary) on which it is going to be using data types of unsigned 8 bit precision with fractional values of the variables scaled to 0-1.0 range.

For some other DSP target which had 16 bit precision floating point values, I had written a code as shown below to convert my full precision(32 bit floating point values [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format)) to half precision(16 bit floating values [binary16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_precision_floating-point_format)) and modeled the target.

```
I had a function 

float bin32tobin16(float val;)
{
float ret;

val = &= ~(0x1fff);
//I used to loose 13 bits of mantissa of a binary32 float to get a 10 bit mantissa in a binary16 float
}
```

You get the idea.

Now But now how do I model this second target which is going to use unsigned 8 bit data types(no floating points available) for values in range between 0-1.0.

How is the conversion from a binary32 bit float to a unsigned 8 bit fractional value going to look like?

Any corner cases I should worry about?

Any pointers would be helpful.

thank you.

-AD.

Comment: Are you looking to convert numbers in the range 0-1.0 to the range 0-255?

Comment: No, looking to convert floats in range 0 to 1.0, to unsigned char(8-bit) which would have fractional values in same range.

Comment: An `unsigned char` has values 0-255. How would you expect to get fractional values from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, there is no *fractional values* as a first-class data type in C. (I'm guessing that you are using C...). You have to decide to represent this using an existing data type, for example you could let an 8 bit unsigned integer type, which have the range 0 - 255, represent the fractional values 0 - 1.0.

This conversion can easily be done using the following:

```
unsigned char to_u8(float x)
{
  return x * 255;
}
```

There are tons of corner cases here: What happens if the value is negative? What if it's bigger than 1.0? What if it's *NaN*? You have to decide if your code should return a reasonable value, or if it should abort.

Secondly, the code you posted indicated that you are trying to manipulate the underlying bit representation of the float. (It's hard to tell, as the code is severely broken.) For float32->float16, this would be feasible, under the assumption that they have the same representation of sign and exponent. However, you typically can't use the same approach here, as there is a big difference in how a floating-point value and an integer is represented.

Answer (score 2):

@Lindydancer, Gabe:

Guess I was not clear in OP, sorry. I have floating point in range 0 to 1.0(no -ve's, no greater than 1.0 values) stored in C data type float. Now assuming there was a data type - unsigned char(8-bit) precision which mapped values between 0 to 1.0 as 0 to 255.

The floating point data tpye can  represent more 'finer' values with better precision(obvious) than the user defined 8-bit unsigned data type which is used to hold values that would be interpreted as fractional values(val / 255).

So my original intention was to map this floating point range/precision to this new unsigned 8-bit range/precision, with of course some loss of data precision in some values which could not be represented in the unsigned-8 bit type.

To do that I mapped the floating point values that I have to this 'new user interpreted/defined' data type by doing

```
unsigned char valconv(float val)
{
    unsigned char ret;

    ret = (unsigned char)(val * 255). 
    return ret;      
}
```

Thank you for pointers.

-AD

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to "accept", if you feel that an answer was appropriate.